# Can I define a new unit that behaves like \ang in siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

The `siunitx` package provides support for "astronomy style" placement of the degree symbol using the `angle-symbol-over-decimal` switch, and for simple entry of degree-minutes-second values using the form

```
\ang{6;7;6.5}
```

Is there a way to used the package's `\DeclareSIUnit` macro to define a corresponding formatting for [right ascension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension) so that, for example, one could use something like

```
\ra[ra-symbol-over-decimal]{5.237}
\ra{5.237} 
\ra{5;15;6.5}
```

to produce (roughly)

[image]

with spacing and other behavior that follows the packages current settings for `\ang`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reading the `siunitx` manual (**→** 5.15 “Symbols”, pp. 62/63) one can find two ways to achieve this:

1. Redefinition of `\SIUnitSymbolDegree`, -`Arcminute` and -`Arcsecond`
2. Using the options `text-`/`math-degree`, -`arcminute` and -`arcsecond` (**→** Table 43, p. 63)

**For both cases applies:**

The new macro `\ra` takes two arguments:

- one optional that gets passed to `\ang` and
- one mandatory (the angle itself).

All “arc format” options (`angle-symbol-over-decimal`, `arc-separator`, …) can be given to `\ra`, too.

### Solution 1

```
\newcommand*{\ra}[2][]{{% extra pair of braces to keep the \def-intion local!
    \def\SIUnitSymbolDegree{\textsuperscript{h}}%
    \def\SIUnitSymbolArcminute{\textsuperscript{m}}%
    \def\SIUnitSymbolArcsecond{\textsuperscript{s}}%
    \ang[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

### Solution 2

```
\newcommand*{\ra}[2][]{%
    \ang[
        math-degree=\textsuperscript{h},
        text-degree=\textsuperscript{h},
        math-arcminute=\textsuperscript{m},
        text-arcminute=\textsuperscript{m},
        math-arcsecond=\textsuperscript{s},
        text-arcsecond=\textsuperscript{s},
        #1]{#2}%
}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\ra}[2][]{{% extra pair of braces for solution 1, doesn't hurt for solution 2
%   \def\SIUnitSymbolDegree{\textsuperscript{h}}%     Solution 1
%   \def\SIUnitSymbolArcminute{\textsuperscript{m}}%  Solution 1
%   \def\SIUnitSymbolArcsecond{\textsuperscript{s}}%  Solution 1
    \ang[
        math-degree=\textsuperscript{h},             % Solution 2
        text-degree=\textsuperscript{h},             % Solution 2
        math-arcminute=\textsuperscript{m},          % Solution 2
        text-arcminute=\textsuperscript{m},          % Solution 2
        math-arcsecond=\textsuperscript{s},          % Solution 2
        text-arcsecond=\textsuperscript{s},          % Solution 2
        #1]{#2}%
}}
\begin{document}
\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal]{5.237}   \par
\ra{5.237}        \par \ra{5;15;6.5}    \par \vspace{2ex}
\ang{2.3;3.4;4.5} \par \ra{2.3;3.4;4.5} \par \ang{2.3;3.4;4.5} \par
\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal,arc-separator=\,]{2.3}           \par \vspace{2ex}
$\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal]{5.237} \quad \ra{5.237} \quad \ra{5;15;6.5}$
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: Excellent! And in addition, and to complete the set, if I want to be able to write something like `\si{hourra}` I'll need to additionally have `\DeclareSIUnit\hourra{\textsuperscript{h}}`; or is there a way to fold that into the definitions above (I'm using #2)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You can certainly do that (minor correction, you'd need to use `\si{\hourra}`). Besides `\ang`/`\ra`, I would rather use the standard `\hour` because a superscript `h` would look weird, especially in something like `\si{\hourra\per\anything}`.

Answer (score 1):

since 2012 the code for the siunitx package has beeen updated and now both solution don't work as expected (but don't throw errors neither, which is a great thing).

The proposed [**Solution 2**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80298/279039) by @Qrrbrbirlbel could be easily corrected using

```latex
\newcommand*{\ra}[2][]{{
    \ang[
        angle-symbol-degree=\textsuperscript{h},
        angle-symbol-minute=\textsuperscript{m},
        angle-symbol-second=\textsuperscript{s},
        #1]{#2}%
}}
```

So the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand*{\ra}[2][]{{
    \ang[
        angle-symbol-degree=\textsuperscript{h},
        angle-symbol-minute=\textsuperscript{m},
        angle-symbol-second=\textsuperscript{s},
        #1]{#2}%
}}

\begin{document}

\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal]{5.237} \par
\ra{5.237}.                           \par 
\ra{5;15;6.5}                         \par 

\vspace{2ex}

\ang{2.3;3.4;4.5}                     \par 
\ra{2.3;3.4;4.5}                      \par 
\ang{2.3;3.4;4.5}                     \par
\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal,arc-separator=\,]{2.3} \par 

\vspace{2ex}

$\ra[angle-symbol-over-decimal]{5.237} \quad \ra{5.237} \quad \ra{5;15;6.5}$

\end{document}
```

is working as expected and outputs

[image]

Hope this was useful!